# Mysql 3 single quotes in a row

Tags: mysql, syntax, quotes

I came across the query below to dynamically convert rows into columns with Mysql. Does anyone know what the the 3 single quotes do before & after the Product_Name field?

```
  SET @sql = NULL;
   SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'count(case when Product_Name = ''',
      Product_Name,
      ''' then 1 end) AS ',
      replace(Product_Name, ' ', '')
    )
  ) INTO @sql
from products;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT pt.partner_name, ', @sql, ' from partners pt
left join sales s
  on pt.part_id = s.partner_id
left join products pd
  on s.product_id = pd.prod_id
group by pt.partner_name');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html says:

> A `'` inside a string quoted with `'` may be written as `''`.

There are lots of examples on that manual page.